# How can I adjust the double icon in angular full calendar?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have a component that contains a fullcalendar, and I use font-awesome for icons.
In particular I use the script "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js",
to use svg icons.
Each time the angular font awesome detection change is triggered, it adds an icon to the full calendar buttons.
How can I avoid this behavior?
Furthermore, even if I change the classes of the buttons, these are not received by the full calendar

the component:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'quix-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() id: string
  @Input() ariaLabel: string
  @Input() height: string
  @Input() locale: string
  @Input() tabIndex: number
  @Input() view: 'timeGridWeek' | 'dayGridMonth' | 'dayGridWeek'
  @Input() events: QuixCalendarEvent[]
  @Input() header: { [key: string]: any }
  @Input() footer: { [key: string]: any }
  @Output() onEventClick = new EventEmitter<any>()
  @Output() onDateClick = new EventEmitter<any>()
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: this.view,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    events: [],
    height: '',
    eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
    dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this),
    headerToolbar: this.header,
    footerToolbar: this.footer,
    buttonIcons: {
      close: 'fas fa-times',
      prev: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
      next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
      prevYear: 'fas fa-angle-double-left',
      nextYear: 'fas fa-angle-double-right'
    },
    locale: '',

  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.height?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.height = changes.height.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.events?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.events = changes.events?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.view?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.initialView = changes.view?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.view?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.headerToolbar = changes.header?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.view?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.footerToolbar = changes.footer?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.locale?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.locale = changes.locale?.currentValue
    }
  }

  eventClick(event: any) {
    this.onEventClick.emit(event)
  }

  dateClick(event: any) {
    this.onDateClick.emit(event)
  }

}
```

the solution, insert in index.html:

```
<script>
    window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }
  </script>
```